# Setting Cron trigger in config when Quartz is deployed as windows service

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have set up Quartz.net server as windows service.I have a job which is scheduled successfully using this. But this Job is running after every minute. I want to schedule the job at 11:00 am and 11:00pm everyday.

But I dont know how to do it. I have a Quartz.Server.Config and a jobs_xml file.

Please suggest me where this configuration will be set and what would be Cron expression for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your job's schedule in two ways. One is through your jobs_xml file, where you need to add trigger information:

```
<job>
  <name>jobName</name>
  <group>simpleGroup</group> 
  <!-- other settings -->
</job>
<trigger>
  <simple>
    <name>triggerName</name> 
    <group>simpleGroup</group>
    <description>SimpleTriggerDescription</description>
    <job-name>jobName</job-name>
    <job-group>jobGroup</job-group>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
    <cron-expression>0 0 11,23 * * ?</cron-expression> <!-- fire every day at 11:00 and 23:00 -->
  </simple>
</trigger>
```

Or programmatically from the scheduler:

```
   IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(this.GetType())
        .WithIdentity("JobName")
        .Build();

   ITrigger strigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
         .WithIdentity("trigger7", "group1")
         .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(11, 0, 0))
         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
         .WithIntervalInHours(12)
         .RepeatForever())
         .Build();

   scheduler.ScheduleJob(detail, trigger);
```

Comment: This runs perfectly smooth